# Wrong characters in my server when I'm doing a Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Windows Server where I'm running my Tomcat with some applications, one of those is Jasper where I'm generating my Jasper Reports. When I export the reports from a batch java process, this report is having wrong characters like they are not UTF-8. I don't know, I set UTF-8 encoding in Jasper.

```
Files.write(Paths.get(informeModificacionesUnificado), Charset.forName("windows-1252").encode(
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(informeModificacionesUnificado)))))
                        .array());
```

I set this code in Java too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, and my experience, the problem can lay in your JRE/JDK imported font type/facets or you are using not appropriate font type in jasper. Some font types are not to be used for printing texts that have special characters like ű ú ó for example. Try debugging with DejaVu Sans in jasper studio, it might help you debugging.